# Why is boolean not seen as a valid output type?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a boolean called `isAcceptedOffer` whereby if it is true, the class `.d-inline` will be added to my span in my component.html

```
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-success text-white d-none" [class.d-inline]="isAcceptedOffer">Accepted</span>
```

The boolean should only be true if message.type === 3. Therefore, I created the following in my component.ts however it is not working

```
isAcceptedOffer(thread: Thread): boolean {
    const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);
    if (message.type === 3) {
        this.isAcceptedOffer = true;
    } else {
        this.isAcceptedOffer = false;
    }
}
```

The error that I can see highlighted is `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type '(thread: Thread) => boolean'.ts(2322)` however I need a type boolean so how can I fix this?

Comment: isAcceptedOffer is a function. you should indicate as a function in html

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet you are trying to reassign your function `isAcceptedOffer` to a boolean which is then expectedly throwing you a type error.

You could try renaming your `isAcceptedOffer` function to something similar such as `evaluateOfferState` which would give you the following snippet:

```
evaluateOfferState(thread: Thread): boolean {
    const message = thread.messages.slice().reverse().find(m => m.type !== 0);
    if (message.type === 3) {
        this.isAcceptedOffer = true;
    } else {
        this.isAcceptedOffer = false;
    }
}
```